# Rows to columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have case with two results sets and i need to merger them into one result set.
Have tired multiple times doing various queries to get the required output but fails.

These are the result sets.

```
select drc.rc_column_name from dyna_report_columns drc;
```

[image: Column Names]

```
select * from REPORT1;
```

[image]

what i am trying to do is to get the results from `rc_column_name` into different columns as a single row on to the next result set.

something like this.
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just alias the columns in your table?

Comment: i am planning on dynamizing the report from the front end, so this is the required output i need to handle it in the front end

Comment: Does the `dyna_report_columns` table have a column for the _position_ of each column name?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes it does `select drc.rc_seq,drc.rc_column_name from dyna_report_columns drc;`

Comment: *"i am planning on dynamizing the report"* - so you want a solution which can handle any number of columns?

Comment: @APC yes i am working on that path as well on the front end level, i am just struggling to get the db query done now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i am planning on dynamizing the report"

You want a solution which can handle any number of columns. So you cannot do this is a regular query. You need to use dynamic SQL to assemble the projection on the fly.

This means a stored procedure or function which executes the dynamic SQL statement and returns a weak ref cursor. Again, it has to be a ref cursor because that is the only construct which can handle a variable projection. Ref cursors are compatible with JDBC ResultSet and ODBC ResultSet, and equivalents in most common front-end programming languages.

Here is a function which uses your posted tables:

```
create or replace function get_any_report return sys_refcursor
is
    stmt varchar2(32767);
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    select 'select 1 as row_type, ' || 
            listagg(''''||rc_column_name||''' as col'||trim(to_char(rc_seq)), ',') within group (order by rc_seq)
            ||' from dual'
    ||' union all   
    select 2  as row_type, r1.*
    from report1 r1
    order by 1, 2'
    into stmt        
    from dyna_report_columns ;
    dbms_output.put_line(stmt);

    open rc for stmt;

    return rc;
end;
/
```

There is an additional column `row_type` which is referenced in the ORDER BY clause to guarantee that the header row is the first row of the result set.

---

Here is [an Oracle LiveSQL Demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/heemernt54d8el34fjej1tdyi). Sorry, you need a free Oracle account to run this, but SQL Fiddle is a bit flaky at the moment.

---

Here is [a SQL Fiddle version of the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac7f69/1) but Fiddle doesn't support DBMS_OUTPUT.

Comment: yes its working perfectly , is it possible to assign fixed alias names for columns which return from this part `listagg(''''||rc_column_name||'''', ',')`

Comment: Like `COL1 | COL2 | COL3` currently its the result set picking up the columns as `User Id | Full Name | Contact Number` ,  preferably the names used in `REPORT1` would be better

Comment: what if i used the `rc_seq` i think it would give me the same result which i expect `listagg(''''||rc_column_name||''' as col'||trim(to_char(rc_seq)), ',')`

Comment: No dramas. Bear in mind that things will get a lot more complicated once you have more than one report to wrangle.